# How can I add '-' before a name to denote hierarchical standings in a recursive stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, stored-procedures, recursive-query

I am attempting to create a tree view within SSMS, utilizing a recursive SP.

Here is my code...

```
@p_Renumber NVARCHAR(7)
AS
DECLARE @orgChart TABLE
(
HMY NUMERIC(18,0) NOT NULL,
RENUMBER NVARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
MANAGER_ID NVARCHAR(7) NULL,
ORGLEVEL NUMERIC(18,0) NOT NULL
);

WITH OrgChartDown (HMY, RENUMBER, MANAGER_ID, ORGLEVEL)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
SELECT HMY, RENUMBER, MANAGER_ID, 0 AS ORGLEVEL
FROM dbo.Employees
WHERE RENUMBER = @p_Renumber

UNION ALL

-- Recursive member definition down tree
SELECT e.HMY, e.RENUMBER, e.MANAGER_ID, o.ORGLEVEL + 1
FROM dbo.Employees e    
INNER JOIN OrgChartDown o ON e.MANAGER_ID = o.RENUMBER
WHERE e.[STATUS] = 1
)

INSERT INTO @orgChart
SELECT HMY, RENUMBER, MANAGER_ID, ORGLEVEL
FROM OrgChartDown;

WITH OrgChartUp (HMY, RENUMBER, MANAGER_ID, ORGLEVEL)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
SELECT HMY, RENUMBER, MANAGER_ID, 0 AS ORGLEVEL
FROM dbo.Employees
WHERE RENUMBER = @p_Renumber

UNION ALL

-- Recursive member definition up tree
SELECT e.HMY, e.RENUMBER, e.MANAGER_ID, o.ORGLEVEL - 1
FROM dbo.Employees e        
INNER JOIN OrgChartUp o ON e.RENUMBER = o.MANAGER_ID
WHERE o.RENUMBER != o.MANAGER_ID --CEO's MANAGER_ID equals own RENUMBER
  AND e.[STATUS] = 1
)

INSERT INTO @orgChart
SELECT HMY, RENUMBER, MANAGER_ID, ORGLEVEL
FROM OrgChartUp
WHERE RENUMBER != @p_Renumber;

SELECT e.HMY, e.RENUMBER, e.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + e.LAST_NAME AS "NAME", 
e.JOB_TITLE, e.MANAGER_ID, o.ORGLEVEL
FROM @orgChart o
INNER JOIN Employees e ON o.HMY = e.HMY
ORDER BY o.ORGLEVEL, e.LAST_NAME
GO
```

I am currently getting results...

```
JOB_TITLE                                       ORGLEVEL
President & CEO                                 -2
Chief Administrative Officer                    -1
Senior Director IT Business Applications        0
Test Tile   EMG --(test entity in database)--   1
Senior Applications Developer                   1
Senior Applications Developer                   1
Contractor                                      1
Senior Applications Developer                   1
Lead Systems Analyst                            1
Lead Systems Analyst                            1
```

(other fields hidden for information security/integrity)

My question is how do I add a dash ("-") as I go down this hierarchical data.

The logic behind it would be to take the ABS(the top most ORGLEVEL), so in this code example the answer would be: ABS(-2) = 2 and then add that to all ORGLEVELS, so that the President and CEO's ORGLEVEL would be equal to 0.
With this newly stored ORGLEVEL I would like to add dashes ("-") to correspond to the value.  Meaning my data would look something like this...

```
JOB_TITLE                                           ORGLEVEL
President & CEO                                     0
-Chief Administrative Officer                       1
--Senior Director IT Business Applications          2
---Test Tile   EMG --(test entity in database)--    3
---Senior Applications Developer                    3
---Senior Applications Developer                    3
---Contractor                                       3
---Senior Applications Developer                    3
---Lead Systems Analyst                             3
---Lead Systems Analyst                             3
```

I know there is a way to do this in the HTML code I am using to bind to my webform, but as this is a dynamic solution I would like to have this done within the stored procedure so it is a simple databind() to the gridview I am using.  Let me know if you have any solutions to this problem.

Comment: I think you'll find that doing it in SQL is much more complex than customizing your data binding. Plus, if you want to display your data in different ways depending on the view, you'll need to incorporate that into the query. Let SQL do its job of retrieving data and HTML do its job of _displaying_ data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your query

```
replicate('-', (ABS((select min(o.ORGLEVEL) from @orgChart)) + o.ORGLEVEL)) + e.JOB_TITLE
```

Comment: You have the right approach, but that `ABS` looks weird. It could just be `o.ORGLEVEL - (select ...)`, no?

Comment: Would you place that in the final select statement or within the select statement in each recursive (up and down) tree select statement? Whilst I tried this out and it works wonders, I have not put it into my SP for fear of placing it in the wrong location. EDIT: Asking for placement due to performance optimization.

Comment: Final Select query

Answer (score -2):

This is a guess, in the absence of sample data, however, I would ***guess*** changing the following:

```
e.JOB_TITLE, e.MANAGER_ID, o.ORGLEVEL
```

to

```
REPLICATE('-',o.ORGLEVEL+2) + e.JOB_TITLE AS JOB_TITLE,
e.MANAGER_ID,
o.ORGLEVEL + 2 AS ORGLEVEL
```

Comment: The OP's query is specifically written to not assume a fixed depth, so hard-coding the depth is not really an appropriate answer.